# How to post multiple <input type=“checkbox” /> as array to Java servlet?

Tags: java, html, arrays, post, checkbox

This question is the same as [How to post multiple <input type="checkbox" /> as array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978781/how-to-post-multiple-input-type-checkbox-as-array-in-php), but I can't make the solution work in my java servlet setup. When using the apporach of adding a [] to the name property of the grouped checkboxes, I only get the first checked option. I am not sure if it is the actual posted array that is containing only one element, or if I'm not accessing it right server side. Here is what I do to check the value in java:

```
@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
    for(String name : request.getParameterMap().keySet()){      
        System.out.println(name +": " + request.getParameter(name));        
    }
}
```

this prints `countries[]: US`, even if I have more checboxes checked after the US-input. the value changes after which checkbox is the first of the checked ones. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="mypage" method="post">
    <input id="cb-country-gb" type="checkbox" name="countries[]" class="hide" value="GB"/>
    <input id="cb-country-us" type="checkbox" name="countries[]" class="hide" value="US"/>
    <input id="cb-country-ge" type="checkbox" name="countries[]" class="hide" value="GE"/>
    <input id="cb-country-es" type="checkbox" name="countries[]" class="hide" value="ES"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use `getParameterValues("countries")`, btw that `[]` is not needed in java  it's a php thing

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the []-clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[getParameterValues][1]` that returns an array of String objects containing all of the values the given request parameter has :

Test that with following code:

```
@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
    for(String name : request.getParameterMap().keySet()){
      for(String value : request.getParameterValues(name)){
          System.out.println(name +": " + value);        
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check multiple checkboxes the request contains multiple parameters with name `countries[]`.

If you call `request.getParameter("countries[]")` only the first parameter value is returned.

Instead you need to use

```
String[] checked = request.getParameterValues("countries[]");
if (checked != null)
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you too. this was very helpful!