# Custom group variables with select in HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, grouping

I am using Laravel Framework to do this PHP app.

I am parsing an XML from an API and the information I get is structured like this:

`projectName`

`projectJobs`- a list with jobs that I am outputting with a `@foreach` into a table (`<td>`);

I want to let the user group the jobs as he wishes. I was thinking of doing this:

```
@foreach($_SESSION['workingProjects'] as $projectName => $projectDetails)
    <tr class="success">
        <td>{{$projectDetails['givenName']}} <p class="text-muted" style="font-size: 0.7em">( {{ $projectName }} )</p></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        @foreach($projectDetails['jobs'] as $jobName => $jobUrl)
           <tr>
               <td>{{$jobName}}</td>
               <td>
                   <select>
                       <option name="group[1][{{$projectDetails['givenName']}}][{{$jobName}}]" value="1">
                           1
                       </option>
                       <option name="group[2][{{$projectDetails['givenName']}}][{{$jobName}}]" value="2">
                           2
                       </option>
                       <option name="group[3][{{$projectDetails['givenName']}}][{{$jobName}}]" value="3">
                           3
                       </option>
                       <option name="group[4][{{$projectDetails['givenName']}}][{{$jobName}}]" value="4">
                           4
                       </option>
                       <option name="group[5][{{$projectDetails['givenName']}}][{{$jobName}}]" value="5">
                           5
                        </option>
                     </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k1">k1</input>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k2">k2</input>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k3">k3</input>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k4">k4</input>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k5">k5</input>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           @endforeach
       @endforeach
   </tbody>
```

Having more projects, I need to have a list of `projectNames` which each have a list of `projectJobs` grouped by the `select` in `1-5` range.

Example:

`PROJECT1 => [ GROUP1 => [ JOB1, JOB2, JOB5 ] GROUP2 => [ JOB3, JOB4 ] ]`;

The problem is that I only get the `crsf_token()` posted and I don't think this is the proper way to do it anyway.

**Clarification:**

I have a list of projects, each project has many jobs, each job needs to be grouped by the user in one of groups. I need to get the user grouping back to the applicaton.

For example `User1` has 3 `Projects` : P1, P2, P3; each project has it's own `Jobs`: J1_1, J1_2, J1_3, J1-4, J1_5, J2_1, J2_2, etc.

I want to enable the `user` to group them as he wishes and send that info to me. For example for `P1`, the `User` groups the jobs like this: `Group1`: J1_2, J1_3, `Group2`: J1_1, J1_4, `Group3`: J1_5

Comment: You have some issues on your html. You are opening the `<tr>` at the beginning an never closing it.
The input field [checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) doesn't have a closing tag. Can you give more details about the expected result and what's exactly the problem, please?

Comment: So I have a list of projects, each project has many jobs, each job needs to be grouped by the user in one of groups. I need to get the user grouping back to the applicaton.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as approach is reasonable, just clean up the html and it should work fine with all the details in the `Request $request` object.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/projects/') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <table>
        @foreach($_SESSION['workingProjects'] as $projectName => $projectDetails)
            <tr class="success">
                <td>{{$projectDetails['givenName']}} <p class="text-muted" style="font-size: 0.7em">( {{ $projectName }} )</p></td>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            @foreach($projectDetails['jobs'] as $jobName => $jobUrl)
                <tr>
                   <td>{{$jobName}}</td>
                   <td>
                       <select name="job[{{$projectDetails['givenName']}}][{{$jobName}}]">
                           <option value="1">
                               Group 1
                           </option>
                           <option value="2">
                               Group 2
                           </option>
                           <option value="3">
                               Group 3
                           </option>
                           <option value="4">
                               Group 4
                           </option>
                           <option value="5">
                               Group 5
                            </option>
                        </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k1" value="k1">k1
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k2" value="k2">k2
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k3" value="k3">k3
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k4" value="k4">k4
                      <input type="checkbox" name="k5" value="k5">k5
                   </td>
               </tr>
           @endforeach
       @endforeach
    </table>

    <button type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>

</form>
```

**Just be careful with the html:**

- for a select tag the syntax is `<select name="">` and in option you have the value `<option value="3">`.
- for a input you need to define the `name` and the `value` in the tag.

Comment: So can I use arrays of arrays such as name="name[value1][value2][value3]" when sending information back to the application through a POST?

Comment: yes, you can :).  if you are using a checkbox just remember to add an additional empty []. Like name="name[value1][value2][value3][]" because you can have multiple values.

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978781/how-to-post-multiple-input-type-checkbox-as-array-in-php